# Functions return and echo

Tags: php

This is my function to show users whit role "php" in database.Problem is if I use echo in function and in html page  everything work fine.
If i change "echo" to "return" and put in html  i get only first row.

Echo example:

```
function showMembersPhp($mysqli)
{ 
    $statement = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members");
    while($row = $statement->fetch_array()){
    if ($row['role'] == 'php') {
      echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['last_online'].'</td>
                <td class="center">'.$row['last_ip'].'</td>
            </tr>';  
        }                                                
    }
}
```

Return example:

```
function showMembersPhp($mysqli)
{ 
    $statement = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members");
    while($row = $statement->fetch_array()){
    if ($row['role'] == 'php') {
      return '<tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['last_online'].'</td>
                <td class="center">'.$row['last_ip'].'</td>
            </tr>';  
        }                                                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a local variable like this and then return it after you iterate entire array:

```
function showMembersPhp($mysqli)
{ 
    $ret = "";
    $statement = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members");
    while($row = $statement->fetch_array()){
    if ($row['role'] == 'php') {
      $ret = $ret. '<tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['last_online'].'</td>
                <td class="center">'.$row['last_ip'].'</td>
            </tr>';  
        }                                                
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return a value, you're exiting the function. That is, exiting the loop. That's why you get only one row.